# Is there a way i can put the arena inside the hallow rectangle?

Tags: python

Is there a way the arena can be inside the hallow rectangle? I need make a moving character inside a hallow 30x30 map without using pygame or anything similar to that.

```
arena = []


size = 30
inner_size = size-2


def make_board(place): 
     print ('*' * size)
     for i in range(inner_size):
        print ('*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')
     print ('*' * size)


     for k in range(30):
        place.append(["0"] * 16)



def list_to_string(alist): 
    for i in alist:
        print(" ".join(i))



make_board(arena) 
list_to_string(arena)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use pygame? It's the best option i can think of.

Comment: It's a school assignment and I'm  not allowed, we have to do it in repl.it